# Как уточнить запрос поиска в гугл-строке?

Tags: google-search

Недавно вспомнил, что в поисковиках можно как-то использовать различные символы, вроде амперсанта, плюса, минуса, разделителя для уточнения запроса поиска.

Можете, пожалуйста, показать перечень подобных "команд" с примерами?

Comment: Это `URL codes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [продвинутым поиском гугла](https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=&hl=ru) или посмотрите [этот раздел справки](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=ru).

Comment: спасибо огромное!